# Layered graphs in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am currently using Graphviz for visualizing control flow graphs. Basically, a (reducible) control flow graph is a DAG plus some edges which point back to nodes in the previous layers. The latter edges should not affect node placement.

Currently, `dot` draws the graphs pretty neatly, but it lacks an easy way to add interactivity (e.g. folding, scrolling, zooming), which is priceless for analysis of very large graphs. Therefore, I selected d3.js as the most mature and feature-rich graphing library.

I'm pretty sure that there is an easy way to draw [layered graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing) (as does `dot`) in d3.js, but I don't seem to recognize it. How do I do that? If this helps, I already perform dominator analysis on my CFG.

Comment: Looks like there's a pending feature request in d3: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/349

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Dagre library for directed graph drawing is rendering-agnostic, but integrates well with d3.js: https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre

Here's a demo rendered using D3: http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/interactive-demo.html

Comment: We have indeed went with the Dagre route: https://github.com/evilmartians/furnace-xray

Comment: you have a broken link

Comment: Here is a link to a Dagre D3 demo: http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/interactive-demo.html